# Database design for eTickets

Tags: database-design, e-commerce

A user can create an order and an order can be for multiple eTickets. Each ticket needs its own row in the table of eTickets. Furthermore, a subsequent order can be assigned to an already existing eTicket if, for example, a use decides to upgrade their eTicket.

So if I've got the standard structure of orders with order details, how do I associate an eTicket with the order that paid for it?

I don't think that just assigning the order to an eTicket works, because if the order is for multiple eTickets and each eTicket is for a different event, say, then how would you know which event that eTicket was for given that that information is already stored within the order detail row? Remember... an order can be for multiple eTickets!

**EDIT**

So this is what I've currently got...

## Order

OrderId PK

## Product

ProductId PK,
EventId FK

## OrderDetail

OrderDetailId PK,
OrderId FK,
ProductId FK,
Quantity

## eTicketAssignment

OrderDetailId FK,
eTicketId FK

## eTicket

eTicketId PK

So if a user buys three etickets for a specific event, then three eTickets are created upon checkout and each one is assigned to the order detail. Payment can also be broken between a deposit and a balance and both orders, via the order detail, are assigned to the same eTicket.

Now I have this working but I think there's something not quite right about it! Should an eticket really be assigned to an order detail? If not then where else would it go?

**EDIT 2**

At its core the e-commerce engine needs to be able to sell anything and eTickets represent a special case of a product that is delivered by creating data - so I kind of need the order details. Also, for eTickets that don't represent fixed accommodation, the quantity on the order detail gives the number of people that can enter on the corresponding *single* eTicket. When accomodation is fixed, such as when one is purchasing chalets in a holiday camp, the quantity on the order detail gives the number of chalets and each chalet gets its own eTicket.

This has been up and running for some time now... I guess I'm just looking for some feedback on the design which seems to require some awkward queries.

For example, given some eTicket how do I work out which event its for? I need to join to three joins from the eTicket table to the product table plus, this returns multiple rows if there are multiple orders assigned to the eTicket which means I need to do some kind of TOP 1 sub-query or aggregate query to get a value.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like this? This way if the eTicket changes, you would update the `ticket_parent` to the previous `ticket_id`.

[image]

**Edit 1**

After your edit, here are my thoughts:

You don't need quantity as it can be calculated by the number of eTickets for the order. I don't see the need for a detailed order table as you can roll it up into a single order. In addition, your current set up does not track changes to the eTicket. The only modifications I would make to my diagram would be to add the `Product` table. I would pose the question whether the event belongs to a ticket or to an order and then perhaps move `event_id` to the `order` table.

Comment: That's interesting... so in effect the order detail becomes an eTicket! So if I wanted this engine to be able to also work with t-shirts and stuff then would you add an order detail table but just not use it for eTickets? (The change tracking is currently done by examining the most recent order detail assigned to the eTicket.)

Comment: @IanWarburton Do you intend to use the same system for eTickets & shirts?

Comment: Yes that's right. I'm looking for it to be at its core a standard e-commerce engine but that built upon it is the ability for some deliverables to be virtual. i.e. eTickets ;) I've added some more info to the question... Obviously its a bit unfair on you to gradually reveal such details!